# Ionic 3 angular 4 angularfire2 module not found

Tags: angular, ionic3

When trying to compile Angular 4 + ionic 3 app using
ionic cordova build android --prod

Im getting the following error:

> Error: ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js Module not found: Error:
>   Can't resolve '../../angularfire2/auth' in
>   'G:serv\ionic\myapp-apk\for-apk\mokenvd\src\app' resolve
>   '../../angularfire2/auth' in
>   'G:serv\ionic\myapp-apk\for-apk\mokenvd\src\app'
>
> using description file:
>   G:serv\ionic\myapp-apk\for-apk\mokenvd\package.json (relative path:
>   ./src/app)
>
> Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration  after
>   using description file:
>   G:serv\ionic\myapp-apk\for-apk\mokenvd\package.json (relative path:
>   ./src/app) 
>       using description file: G:serv\ionic\myapp-apk\for-apk\mokenvd\package.json (relative path:
>   ./angularfire2/auth)      no extension

Here is my package.json

```html
{
  "name": "mokenvd",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/forms": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/http": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/router": "^4.1.3",
    "@ionic-native/contacts": "^4.3.1",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^4.4.2",
    "@ionic-native/device": "^4.3.1",
    "@ionic-native/facebook": "^4.4.2",
    "@ionic-native/globalization": "^4.4.2",
    "@ionic-native/keyboard": "^4.4.2",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.12.1",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.12.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^8.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^0.1.0",
    "angular2-signaturepad": "^2.6.1",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
    "copyfiles": "^1.2.0",
    "cordova-android": "6.4.0",
    "cordova-custom-config": "^4.0.2",
    "cordova-ios": "^4.5.4",
    "cordova-plugin-compat": "^1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-contacts": "^2.3.1",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.7",
    "cordova-plugin-facebook4": "^1.9.1",
    "cordova-plugin-globalization": "^1.0.8",
    "cordova-plugin-inapppurchase": "^1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.3.0",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "d3": "^4.11.0",
    "ionic": "^3.13.2",
    "ionic-angular": "3.7.1",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "moment": "^2.19.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.0",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "2.1.4",
    "@types/c3": "^0.4.44",
    "@types/d3": "4.10.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.6.0",
    "firebase": "^4.6.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.8.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "karma": "^1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
    "typescript": "2.3.4"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-contacts": {},
      "cordova-plugin-globalization": {},
      "cordova-plugin-facebook4": {
        "APP_ID": "11111111111111",
        "APP_NAME": "mokenvd"
      }
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android",
      "ios"
    ]
  }
}
```

Tried

1. updating angularfire to its latest version:

   npm install angularfire2 firebase promise-polyfill --save

> Resulted by a different error: Metadata version mismatch for module
>   ../node_modules/angularfire2/index.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3,

2. Downgrading to rc3 :

   npm install angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.3 --save

> Resulted by the same error

3. Downgrading to rc2 :
   npm install angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.2 --save

> Resulted by the same error

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Remove angularfire2 firebase from package.json and save file. Delete node_modules then npm i and try this command npm i firebase@4.3.1 angularfire2@4.0.0-rc.0 --save (Make sure you that have removed angular fire and firebase completely)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47606065/ionic-cordova-build-android-prod-release-fails-with-cant-resolve-app-modul

Comment: But im using  AngularFireList so i need angularfire2 ver 5